# Why ArrayBlockingQueue must have bound, while LinkedBlockingQueue not?

Tags: java, queue, blockingqueue

When I instantiate `ArrayBlockingQueue`, I must also put **int capacity** in its constructor. Same thing doesn't apply for `LinkedBlockingQueue`. I am interested in why is that?

Of course, I can also put bound in `LinkedBlockingQueue`, but it is optimal. Why is it optimal here, and not in `ArrayBlockingQueue`? Couldn't `ArrayBlockingQueue` have initial capacity on default like `ArrayList` has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) says.

> This is a classic "bounded buffer", in which a fixed-sized array holds elements inserted by producers and extracted by consumers. **Once created, the capacity cannot be changed.** Attempts to put an element into a full queue will result in the operation blocking; attempts to take an element from an empty queue will similarly block.

Since the capacity is fixed and can't change, it is up to the user of the class to decide when the queue should start to block.

The documentation for [LinkedBlockQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) says

> An **optionally-bounded blocking** queue based on linked nodes. This queue orders elements FIFO (first-in-first-out). The head of the queue is that element that has been on the queue the longest time. The tail of the queue is that element that has been on the queue the shortest time. New elements are inserted at the tail of the queue, and the queue retrieval operations obtain elements at the head of the queue. Linked queues typically have higher throughput than array-based queues but less predictable performance in most concurrent applications.

> The **optional capacity bound constructor argument serves as a way to prevent excessive queue expansion.** The capacity, if unspecified, is equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Linked nodes are dynamically created upon each insertion unless this would bring the queue above capacity.

In this case, the blocked based on a supplied capacity. If specified, that blocking capacity is enforced the same as the `ArrayBlockingQueue`

Comment: I read the docs already, thanks anyway. But that doesn't actually answer my question. I was wondering why is Linked capacity optimal, and Array's not.

Comment: I think you meant `optional` (or maybe not).  Anyway, it's  because it is an optionally bounded queue.  That is just a feature of the class which is different than `ArrayBlockingQueue`.  And your question also asked why it couldn't be done like an `ArrayList`.  And as I explained, the `ArrayBlockingQueue` capacity is fixed, whereas `ArrayList`  isn't because `ArrayList` does  not block.

Comment: Yeah I follow you :) I understand that is how they are implemented, but why not have same implementation (make both optimal or not for example). And then decide if you would like array or linkedList structure.

Comment: Just a guess but it could be because LinkedLists grow automatically and don't require reserved space.  The max capacity of a linkedList (which it would probably never reach BTW) is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  To do the same in an ArrayBlockingQueue the array would have to be that big.  If it has to continually copy like an arrayList and update itself that would be a performance hit.  To know for certain you could email `Doug Lea` and ask him.  He wrote both classes.

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it.